# How could i save all the hashes generated from jpg images into a csv file and not only the last one?

Tags: python, imagehash

```
import imagehash
from PIL import Image
import glob
import numpy as np

image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('/home/folder/*.jpg'):
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
    hash = imagehash.average_hash(im)
    print(hash)
    list_rows = [[hash]]
    np.savetxt("numpy_test.csv", list_rows, delimiter=",", fmt='% s')
```

> how to save all the hashes generated into the same csv file and not only the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you're overwriting your `list_rows` variable for every step in the loop. You should append to the list instead, and then write the content of the list to your csv.

```py
import imagehash
from PIL import Image
import glob
import numpy as np

image_list = []
list_rows = []

for filename in glob.glob('/home/folder/*.jpg'):
    im = Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
    img_hash = imagehash.average_hash(im)
    print(img_hash)
    list_rows.append([img_hash])

np.savetxt("numpy_test.csv", list_rows, delimiter=",", fmt='% s')
```

PS: Try not to override builtin (like [hash](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash)) [that may be dangerous](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#builtins-the-built-in-scope) !